# Seeking License Fees / Restrictions for MapQuest Light (OSM) Basemap

Tags: geospatial, licensing, openstreetmap

Can anyone direct me to a link that has the Usage Agreement / Licensing Fees / User Restrictions or metadata for a basemap called MapQuest Light (OSM)?

To View the Basemap, it can be found on this website:

https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/

Select the drop down and choose MapQuest Light (OSM).

Thanks all, I haven't been able to locate any metadata, a user license agreement, or any specifics on this basemap.

Comment: open source stack exchange is where i see most licensing chatter. not sure if this is a better fit here, just sharing.

Comment: is there any reason to think it wouldn't be licensed under the same as OSM? https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright